# Nested If Statements Matlab

Tags: matlab, if-statement, nested-loops

my code is basically error checking, obviously not all the error checks will meet the condition at the same iteration. What I basically did is an infinite loop and within it I made several loops (each dealing with a specific error check), here's my code:

```
while(1)

if(error1(x) < 0.001)

*condition statements*

break;

else

while(error1(x) >= 0.001)

*condition statements*

end
```

and it goes on in the same manner for all the other error checks. At the last of the code I wrote this:

```
if(error1(x) < 0.001)

if(error2(x) < 0.001)
```

it goes in a nested if statement till the last error check condition and then:

```
break;

end;

x = x+1;

end
```

I currently don't have access to Matlab, do you guys think it'll work? If not, could you please provide guidance on how to exit the infinite loop as soon as all conditions for the error checks have been met? Thanks in advance. My only problem is exiting the infinite loop.

Comment: Oops forgot my manners, thanks in advance!

Comment: If you don't have access to matlab, I suggest to use octave which is free and supports basically the same language.

Comment: No the thing is, I'll have access to it tomorrow, I just want to know if this method will work and I don't need to work further on it now, but much thanks on the advice, I'll look into it.

Comment: Your code does not work because it is syntactically incorrect. Some `end` are missing. I have no idea what you are trying to implement, because I don't understand your description.

Comment: Do you expect multiple conditions to be true, or do you only need to handle the first one that is true? Because if only one condition is expected to be true, a `switch` statement would be much cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a nice way to do multiple tests, but only do something on the first one that is successful:

```
x = 5;
switch true
    case x > 10
        fprintf(1, 'x is greater than 10\n')
    case x > 8
        fprintf(1, 'x is greater than 8\n')
    case x < 6
        fprintf(1, 'x is less than 6\n')
    case y == 3
        fprintf(1, 'y equals three\n')
    otherwise
        fprintf(1, 'no conditions were met\n')
end
```

It leaves the code very clean and easy to understand / modify. Unlike in C, where you can "fall through" from one case to the next, in Matlab you can only execute one case (and then you will drop out). However, it would be possible to have multiple conditions in a single case, using an OR construction: `case x < 6 | y > 3` for example would run if either condition is met (and no earlier conditions were true).

Can't be sure this is what you wanted as the question was terribly unclear; but maybe you will find this useful. Feel free to ask clarifying questions in the comments.